# Heroku does pre load some specific gems?

Tags: heroku, bundle, daemons, gemfile

Similar questions was asked on those links but the answer do not solve my problem.

[why does heroku not list the same gems as i have locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616041/why-does-heroku-not-list-the-same-gems-as-i-have-locally)

[Rails 3: Bundle Exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6748100/rails-3-bundle-exec)

I have the following Gemfile :

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails'
gem 'daemons', '=1.0.10'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'locomotive_cms', :git => 'git://github.com/locomotivecms/engine.git', :require => 'locomotive/engine'
```

In my Gemfile.lock there so :

```
daemons (1.0.10)
delayed_job (3.0.0.pre4)
  activesupport (~> 3.0)
  daemons (= 1.0.10)
```

But for some obscure reason to me, I get this error on Heroku :

```
You have already activated daemons 1.1.0, but your Gemfile requires daemons 1.0.10. Consider using bundle exec
```

So does it means Heroku adds someway this gem version, or ... I misunderstood something about bundle ?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku already installs daemons 1.1.0 in your stack and the delayed_job gem requires the version 1.0.10 because, they said, they had problems with other versions.
I've talked with the Heroku ruby team and they said that it would require too many changes in their dependancies to fix this, so they won't. So you either solve it like described [here](http://alextoul.posterous.com/solved-you-have-already-activated-daemons-110) and change your stack (which I would not suggest if you are running a serious production environment) or you can use the delayed job from [my repo](https://github.com/matteodepalo/delayed_job) and avoid the error at your own risk. What I did was simply to change the dependency on the daemons version.